# Hi I am new in react.js I am working on useState hooks and I have got This error any solution please

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React Hook "useState" is called in function "app" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import logo from './logo.svg'
    import Person from './Person/Person';
    import './App.css';


    const app = props =>{
      const [Personstat, setPersonstate]= useState({
        persons : [
          {name:"Amir", age:"25"},
          {name:"Amir Yousaf", age:"22225"},
          {name:"Amir Yousaf Maher", age:"25"}
        ]
      });
     const switchNameHandler = () =>{
        //alert('hello Listener');
        setPersonstate( {
    persons : [
            {name:"Qasin", age:"23"},
            {name:"Qasin Yousaf", age:"22"},
            {name:"Qasin Yousaf Maher", age:"215"}
          ]
        })};
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello  I am trying to learn js </h1>
          <Person name={Personstat.persons[0].name} 
age={Personstat.persons[0].age}/>
          <Person name={Personstat.persons[1].name} 
age={Personstat.persons[1].age}>I am try my best for learning</Person>
          <Person name={Personstat.persons[2].name} 
age={Personstat.persons[1].age}/>
          <button onClick={switchNameHandler}>Switch Name</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default app;
```

Comment: How are you using `App` in your project? `<App />` or `App()`?

Comment: As Eddie stated; you should do: `const App` and `export default App`, then `import App from` and render it with `<App />` you have to start your components with upper case characters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A React component name has to start with Capital letters. Change your component name to App.

Comment: `app` is a local variable in this file module scope. Without seeing how OP is importing it, this answer is only a (misleading) guess.

Comment: the problem is here:  export default app, exporting component like this will not work

Comment: Nope, the name of the default export doesn't matter.

Comment: can you please show how to import it then, it will be helpful

Comment: `import WhateverNameYouWantWillWork from './app';` if it is a default export: `export default irrelevantLocalVariableName;`

Comment: Though it is a good practice to keep it consistent and use the same name whenever possible, just to avoid confusion when reading the code.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: Thanks I have got it